# Finding the equation of a circle given three points on the circle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, circles

Problem:

Find an equation for the circle though the points $(2,3)$, $(3,2)$ and $(-4,3)$
Answer:

One of the general form of a circle is:
$$ x^2 + y^2 + ax + by + c = 0  $$
Hence we have:
\begin{align*}
4 + 9 + 2a + 3b + c &= 0 \,\,\, \text{ This is for the first point. } \\
9 + 4 + 3a + 2b + c &= 0 \,\,\, \text{ This is for the second point. }\\
16 + 9 - 4a + 3b + c &= 0 \,\,\, \text{ This is for the third point. }\\
\end{align*}
Now, I have a system of 3 linear equations. We put them in standard form.
\begin{align*}
2a + 3b + c &= -13 \\
3a + 2b + c &= -13 \\
-4a + 3b + c &= -16 \\
\end{align*}
Now, we will solve for $a$ using Cramer's rule.
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 3 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 \\
-4 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &=2 \begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} - 3 \begin{vmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
-4 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
-4 & 3 \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 2 - 3 = -1 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
-4 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 3 + 4 = 7 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
-4 & 3 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 9 + 8 = 17 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 3 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 \\
-4 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 2(-1) -3(7) + 17 = -2 - 21 + 17 = -6 \\
%
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 3 & 1 \\
-13 & 2 & 1 \\
-16 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -13 \begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} - 3 \begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 1 \\
-16 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 2 \\
-16 & 3 \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 2 - 3 = -1 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 1 \\
-16 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -13 + 16 = 3 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 2 \\
-16 & 3 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -39 + 32 = -7 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 3 & 1 \\
-13 & 2 & 1 \\
-16 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -13( -1) - 3(3) - 7 = 13 - 9 - 7 = -3 \\
a &= \frac{-3}{-6} \\
a &= \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & -13 & 1 \\
3 & -13 & 1 \\
-4 & -16 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 2 
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 1 \\
-16 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} + 13 \begin{vmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
-4 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}
3 & -13 \\
-4 & -16  \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 1 \\
-16 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -13 + 16 = 3 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
-4 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 3 + 4 = 7 \\ 
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & -13 \\
-4 & -16  \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -48 - 52 = 100 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & -13 & 1 \\
3 & -13 & 1 \\
-4 & -16 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 2(3) + 13(7) - 100 = 6 + 91 - 100 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & -13 & 1 \\
3 & -13 & 1 \\
-4 & -16 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -3 \\
b &= \frac{-3}{-6} \\
b &= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
Now we take the first equation and solve for $c$.
\begin{align*}
2a + 3b + c &= -13 \\
2\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)  + 3\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) + c &= -13 \\
1 + \frac{3}{2} + c &= -13 \\
c &= - 13 - \frac{3}{2} - \frac{2}{2} \\
c &= -\frac{31}{2}
\end{align*}
Now we subsitute back into the general form of the circle we started with:
\begin{align*}
x^2 + y^2 + ax + by + c &= 0 \\
x^2 + y^2 + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) x + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)y - \frac{31}{2} &= 0  \\
2x^2 + 2y^2 + x + y - 32 &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
However, the book gets:
$$ 2x^2 + 2y^2 + x + y - 23 = 0 $$
I claim that the point $(2,3)$ goes through my equation but not the book's equation. Am I right? Is the book right?

I copied the book's answer incorrectly. The book's answer is:
$$ x^2 + y^2 + 2x + 2y - 23 = 0 $$

In addition, after correcting for the wrong
constant (e.g $-16$ should have been -$25$), I was able to get the correct answer. Here is my correct answer.

Answer:

One of the general form of a circle is:
$$ x^2 + y^2 + ax + by + c = 0  $$.
Hence we have:
\begin{align*}
4 + 9 + 2a + 3b + c &= 0 \,\,\, \text{ This is for the first point. } \\
9 + 4 + 3a + 2b + c &= 0 \,\,\, \text{ This is for the second point. }\\
16 + 9 - 4a + 3b + c &= 0 \,\,\, \text{ This is for the third point. }\\
\end{align*}
Now, I have a system of 3 linear equations. We put them in standard form.
\begin{align*}
2a + 3b + c &= -13 \\
3a + 2b + c &= -13 \\
-4a + 3b + c &= -25 \\
\end{align*}
Now, we will solve for $a$ using Cramer's rule.
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 3 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 \\
-4 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &=2 \begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} - 3 \begin{vmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
-4 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
-4 & 3 \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 2 - 3 = -1 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
-4 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 3 + 4 = 7 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
-4 & 3 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 9 + 8 = 17 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 3 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 \\
-4 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 2(-1) -3(7) + 17 = -2 - 21 + 17 = -6 \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 3 & 1 \\
-13 & 2 & 1 \\
-25 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -13 \begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} - 3 \begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 1 \\
-25 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 2 \\
-25 & 3 \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 2 - 3 = -1 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 1 \\
-25 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -13 + 25 = 12 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 2 \\
-25 & 3 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -39 + 50 = 11 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 3 & 1 \\
-13 & 2 & 1 \\
-25 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -13(-1) - 3(12) + 11 = 13 - 36 + 11 = -12 \\
a &= \frac{-12}{-6} \\
a &= 2 \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & -13 & 1 \\
3 & -13 & 1 \\
-4 & -25 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 2 
% continue here
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 1 \\
-25 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} + 13 \begin{vmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
-4 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}
3 & -13 \\
-4 & -25 \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
\begin{vmatrix}
-13 & 1 \\
-25 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -13 + 25 = 12 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
-4 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 3 + 4 = 7 \\ 
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & -13 \\
-4 & -25  \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -75 - 4(13) = -127 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & -13 & 1 \\
3 & -13 & 1 \\
-4 & -25 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= 2(12) + 13(7) - 127 = 24 + 91 - 127 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & -13 & 1 \\
3 & -13 & 1 \\
-4 & -16 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} &= -12 \\
b &= \frac{-12}{-6} \\
b &= 2
\end{align*}
Now we take the first equation and solve for $c$.
\begin{align*}
2a + 3b + c &= -13 \\
2( 2)  + 3( 2 ) + c &= -13 \\
10 + c &= -13 \\
c &= -23
\end{align*}
Now we substitute back into the general form of the circle we started with:
\begin{align*}
x^2 + y^2 + ax + by + c &= 0 \\
x^2 + y^2 + 2x + 2y - 23 &= 0  \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Did you mean $31$ where you wrote $32$?

Comment: Using maxima solve([4+9+2*a+3*b+c,9+4+3*a+2*b+c,16+9 - 4*a+3*b+c],[a,b,c]);
[[a = 2, b = 2, c = - 23]] ,  $x^2 + y^2 + 2x + 2y - 23 = 0$

Comment: Did you mean $-25$ where you wrote $-16$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I meant $31$. Good catch.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Are  you saying that this equation is wrong? $-4a + 3b + c &= -16$. If so, I think you are right.

Comment: You made a mistake at the beginning, that carries through the rest of your calculations.  $(- 4)^2 + 3^2 = 25$ not 16

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternate aproach.

Lets label our points

A = (2,3)
B = (3,2)
C = (-4,2)

The equation of the line containing AB is $x+y = 5$
Its perpendicular bisector is $x=y$

The equation of $AC$ is $y = 3$
And the perpendicular bisector is $x = -1$

The center of the circle then is $(-1,-1)$

And the square of the distance from the center to any of these points $3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$

$(x+1)^2 + (y+1)^2 = 25$

Answer (score 2):

segment bisectors meet in the circle center

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Neither answer appears to be correct.  The correct answer is $$(x+1)^2 + (y+1)^2 = 5^2,$$ or $$x^2 + 2x + y^2 + 2y - 23 = 0.$$  This can be easily verified via substitution of the three points.

Another way to solve for the equation of the circumcircle is to observe that if the circle passes through $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$, the circumcenter must lie on the line $y = x$, because this line is the perpendicular bisector of the line segment joining these two points.  Moreover, the side of the triangle joining $(-4,3)$ and $(2,3)$ has perpendicular bisector $x = \frac{-4+2}{2} = -1$.  Therefore, the circumcenter is located at the intersection of these two lines, hence the circle's center is $(-1,-1)$ and its radius is simply the distance to any vertex:  $$r = \sqrt{(3-(-1))^2 + (2-(-1))^2} = 5.$$  Hence the equation of the circle is as claimed above.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach was fine, but you made a couple of computational errors.

The system should be $2a+3b+c=-13,\tag1$

$3a+2b+c=-13,\tag2$

$-4a+3b+c=-\color{red}{25}.\tag3$

Subtracting $(1$) from $(2)$ shows that $a-b=0$ or $a=b$.

Then we have $5a+c=-13$ and $-a+c=-25$; subtracting those yields $6a=12$ or $a=2$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

We know from circle theorems that the perpendicular bisector of a chord of a circle passes through the circle's centre. Treating these $3$ points as $2$ chords and finding the equation of their perpendicular bisectors, the intersection point of the $2$ bisectors will be the centre of the circle.